# When using react router does it load all the routes at the beginning

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to create a multipage react app, but I want to reduce the bandwidth. So if I use react-router will it load all the pages at the beginning or will it road when called.

Answer (score 3):

The entire react app is loaded initially regardless of whether you are using react-router. A page is not rendered unless the route is in effect. Using react router will not increase your load time in the way that you are thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will load all components and use all the bandwidth to do so.

To achieve what you want, you need to use code splitting.

- [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#code-splitting)
- [React Router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/code-splitting)

Comment: But when we use code splitting, let's say for the react pages the element in react-router with suspense... It still requests that page right? it's just not rendering the components which are inside the suspense?...